# Solution of non-linear differential equation $y''+ay'+b\sin(y)\cos(y)=c$, where $a,b,c$ are constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a project, in that project model I arrived at a differential equation. For further analysis, I need the solution of this equation. I tried to solve the equation but couldn't get success. Please anyone give some idea to solve this.

$y''+ay'+b\sin(y)\cos(y)=c$, where $a,b,c$ are the constants means they are combinations of parameter values of real life materials.

If $y'=0$ then it can be solved by multiplying the equation by $y'$ and integrating it. But, in the present case I'm not getting any clue. Thanks in advance.

Note: Ideas in the direction of approximated solution are also invited.

Comment: "Very important for my project work" explain how, give as much detail for the meaning of the constants, etc. Approximations are at the heart of nonlinear equations and knowing exactly which are valid and which are not would be necessary information for a potential answerer.

Comment: I am working on a project, in that project model I arrived at this differential equation. For further analysis, I need the solution of this equation. a, b, c are the constants means they are combinations of parameter values of real life materials.

Comment: @NinadMunshi If you have some idea on approximated solution, you share your idea. Leave the validity of solution on me, I will check that.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "solved".  In the $a=0$ case (which you describe as solvable), the problem reduces to the large-angle pendulum, which can only be solved via quadratures.

Comment: @JacobManaker  I mean to say, if equation is $y''+bsinycosy=0$ then $y'y''+\frac{b}{2}sin2y y'=cy'$. Now, on integration we can reduce it to $(y')^2=...$. After that we can do something. But in my case $a$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: Why someone voted to close this question ? The question is well understandable and of interest. The OP shows the few that he did to solve the problem, but who could do more?

Comment: @JJacquelin forgive that person, may be he didn't understand my problem or did this by mistake.

Comment: Does it help to write $\sin{(y)}\cos{(y)}=\frac{1}{2} \sin{(2y)}$ and get a linear aproximation via its power series around your initial value?

Comment: @Luciano I am trying $\sin{(y)}\cos{(y)}=\frac{1}{2} \sin{(2y)}\approx \frac{1}{2}.2y=y$

Comment: @aryan To make approximations it is useful to know in what regime one is interested. Specifically, in this case: the ratios of the parameters $c/b$? Is this large? Close to zero? Close to one? Negative? What does $y$ represent? Is it the deviation from equilibrium of some quantity? I presume the lack of this type of information is the cause of the close votes

Comment: @Sal Here $y=\theta$ (azimuthal angle). $b/c$ is positive and close to $1$. could you please suggest something in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One solution is $y=\frac12\arcsin\left(\frac{2c}{b}\right)+n\pi$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for $y\approx 0\implies \sin(2y)\approx 2y$, we can solve the ODE since it becomes linear with constant coefficients, $y=y_h+y_p$ and $y_h=e^{\lambda x}$ gives $y=\frac{c}{b}+A_1e^{0.5\left(-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}\right)x}+A_2e^{0.5\left(-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}\right)x}$

Answer (score 4):

$$y''+ay'+b\sin(y)\cos(y)=c$$
This ODE is  of autonomous kind. Thus the order can be reduced, that is to say transforming it to a first order ODE.

Change of variables :
$$\begin{cases}
Y=\frac{dy}{dx}\\
X=y
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dY}{dX}\frac{dX}{dx}=\frac{dY}{dX}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dY}{dX}Y$$
$$\boxed{Y\frac{dY}{dX}+aY+b\sin(X)\cos(X)=c}$$
This is the first order nonlinear ODE to be solved for $Y(X)$.

But the problem is far to be solved because this is an Abel's differential equation of the second kind.

Of course the solution exists but in general cannot be expressed with a finite number of standard functions. That is to say, up to now no special function has been defined and standardized in order to analytically express the solutions on a formal manner in the general case.

Conclusion : Don't expect a definitive answer. Better try to approximately solve your problem in terms of series expansion or thanks to numerical methods.

Comment: How does one use a series for Abel’s differential equation of the second kind?

Comment: This would probably be even more arduous than using series directly for the original second order equation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a series expansion assuming the function has a Taylor Series:

$$y’’=-ay’-\frac b2 \sin(2y)+c=\implies y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{y^{(n)}(k)(x-k)^n}{n!}$$

Let $y(k)=c_0,y’(k)=c_1$ then,

$$y’’(k)=-ay’(k)-\frac b2\sin(2y(k))+c=-ac_1-\frac b2\sin(2c_1)+c$$
$$y’’’(k)=-a y’’(k)-by’(k)\cos(2y(k))= -a^2c_1+\frac {ab}2\sin(2c_1)-ac -bc_1\cos(2c_0)$$
$$y^{(4)}(k)= a^3c_1-\frac {a^2b}2\sin(2c_1)+a^2c +abc_1\cos(2c_0)+abc_1+\frac {b^2}2\sin(2c_1)-bc+2bc_1^2\sin(2c_0)$$
$\vdots$

There is a complicated pattern. Continue the process to find the series expansion of the general solution.

Answer (score 1):

On scaling variables $t=as$, $x(t)=2y(s)$ and renaming constants $\beta=b/a^2$ , $\alpha=2c/a^2$, the equation reads

$$\tag{1}
x''+x'+\beta \sin x=\alpha
$$

This corresponds to the `damped pendulum with constant tangential force'. We can learn a lot about the equation without an exact solution. First, let us study the phase portrait. Let $v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$ then we can plot the vector field $(x',v')$ in the $x$-$v$ plane.

[image]

The image above shows the vector field (black) and an example trajectory (blue). On the left $\alpha=0.7$, $\beta=2.8$ and on the right $\alpha=1.2$, $\beta=0.5$. These are the two qualitatively different regimes, depending on which of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is larger. The vector field is $2\pi$ periodic in the $x$ direction.

An equilibrium solution (left image), $x(t)=x_0=\text{constant}$, $x'=0=x''$ exists when

$$
\sin x_0=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}
$$

If $\alpha<\beta$, there are two equilibrium points. If $\alpha=\beta$, there is one, and if $\alpha>\beta$ there are none. Any such points are $2\pi$ periodic. If an equilibrium solution exists, then deviations from equilibrium $x(t)=x_0+x_1(t)$ are governed by the approximate linear differential equation (by substituting $x(t)=x_0+x_1(t)$into (1) and formally expanding everything in small $x_1$)

$$\tag{2}
x_1''+x_1'+x_1\cos x_0=0
$$

This is the damped oscillator equation. Note that $x_0$ is a known constant. The solutions are exponentials, and may be found by substituting $x_1(t)=e^{rt}$. When you do this, you will learn about the stability of the equilibrium points. I think that when they are two equilibria, one is stable and the other is not, based on the sign of $\cos x_0$. Furthermore, the stable point is attractive and the system always flows towards it (modulo the $2\pi$ periodicity). You'll need to treat the case $\alpha=\beta$ separately, I find that the single equilibrium point is still attractive in this case.

When $\alpha>\beta$, the system flows to an approximate steady state (right image), in which $x'$ is of bounded variation. To determine this, study the solution of (1) when $x'' \ll x'$, that is

$$\tag{3}
x' \sim \alpha-\beta\sin x \qquad,\qquad t\to\infty 
$$

This equation may be solved exactly, the result is (the integration constant disappears from the expression for large $t$)

$$\tag{4}
x(t)=2\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\beta}{\alpha}-\sqrt{1-(\beta/\alpha)^2}\tan\left(\frac{\alpha t}{2}\sqrt{1-(\beta/\alpha)^2}\right) \right]
$$

Differentiating (4) to find explicitly $x'$, then finding the maxima and minima of $x'$ in the limit of large $t$ we find

$$\tag{5}
\alpha-\beta<v_\infty<\alpha+\beta
$$

Where $v_\infty$ is the large time asymptotic velocity. The red lines in the image on the right are the bounds $\alpha \pm \beta$.

**In conclusion**

The large $t$ behavior of the system is either to approach an attractive fixed point

$$
x(t)=x_0+x_1(t) \qquad,\qquad \alpha\leq \beta
$$

Where $x_1$ varies like $e^{-t}$, so the approach is exponential. Or, if $\alpha>\beta$, the system approaches the periodic motion described by (4) with the velocity described by (5). These behaviors are all independent of the initial conditions.